# question related to formatting . Usage of format() in python

Tags: python, format

could anyone explain how format()  works in python? where to use it, and how to use it?. I am not getting even I about this keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regarding it as a kind of string replacement.

```
{} part in the string -> string.format() content
```

Definition: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

A pratical example can be like this:

```
base_url = 'www.xxxx.com/test?page={}'
for i in range(10):
    url = base_url.format(i)
    do sth
```

Answer (score 0):

The format() method formats the specified value(s) and insert them inside the string's placeholder.

```
txt1 = "My name is {fname}, I'm {age}".format(fname = "John", age = 36)
```

Here fname will be replaced by John and age will be replaced by 36, if you print txt1.

Alternatively you can use f strings .
eg:

```
fname= "John"
age= 36
print(f"My name is {fname}, I'm {age}")
```

Even it will print the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Format is often applied as a `str`-type method: `txt.format(...)`, where `type(txt)='str'`.

This function is used to insert values inside string's placeholders. Placeholders are curly brackets `{}` placed inside a string and the `format()` method returns a formatted string with the values plugged into the string.

This function also enables formatting different type of variables in different ways. E.g. `float` with value `0.0001` can be represented in floating point representation: `0.0001` or scientific representation `1e-4` using different specifires.

Usage:

```
txt = "My name is {name}. I'm {age} years old."
print(txt.format(name="Dan", age=32))
```

Will output: `'My name is Dan. I'm 32 years old.'`

You can use positional arguments as well:

```
txt = "My name is {}. I'm {} years old."
print(txt.format("Dan", 32))
```

Where the values are taken by their order.
This will output the same result.

To format with different formatting you can use specifiers:

```
txt = "Decimal numbers: {number:d}"
print(txt.format(number=8340))
```

```
txt = "Fix point numbers: {number:.2f}"
print(txt.format(number=3.1415))
```

There are other specifiers that have other formatting behavior like centering some value to match some desired width:

```
txt = "{center:^20}"
print(txt.format(center='center'))
```

This will output `'       center       '` which contains exactly 20 characters.

There are many more formatting options that you can browse [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)
or in many other rescorces.

Comment: thanks, dude! , I  will look at the link.